# How to keep inline-blocks and footer seperate?

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to have a side-nav on my website, but I don't know how to make it as a block that will stop when it hits the footer tag. I tried following the code provided by W3S, but it got the side nav stuck if it was under `position: fixed`, so I tried doing `position: absolute`. Not sure what to do. The current code that I have right now surpasses the footer.

HTML:

```
<!-- Side Nav Starts Here -->

<span id="side-nav">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Starting Japanese</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Particles</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vocabulary</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Syntax</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Grammar</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kanji</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</span>    

<!-- Side Nav Ends Here -->
<!-- Content Starts Here -->

<span id="content">
<article>
    <h3>Using This</h3>
    <p>I guess you say something about this page's objective? Eh,
    <br>I'll come back to it later, I suppose.
    <br>A test
    <br>Another Text. okay.
    <br><br>asd<br>asd<br><br>asd<br><br><br><br>asdasd<br>asd<br>
    <br>asd<br>asd<br><br>asd<br><br><br><br>asdasd<br>asd<br></p>
</article>
</span>

<!-- Content Ends Here -->
<!-- Footer Starts Here -->

<footer id="foot">
<hr>
<p>Follow me on:</p>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/justchavz/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/instagram-logo.jpg" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/JustChavz" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/twitter_logo.jpg" alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
<a href="http://chavezphotography.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/tumblr_logo.jpg"></a>
<hr>
</footer> 

<!-- Footer Ends Here -->
```

CSS:

```
/* Side Nav Starts Here */

#side-nav {
display: grid;
background-color: #0f0f0f;
width: 12em;
border: 6px solid #0f0f0f;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

#side-nav nav {
content: "";
display: block;
border: 5px solid #ffffff;
}

#side-nav ul {
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#side-nav ul li {
display: block;
width: 9em; /* Ask how to get the precised measure */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: inherit;
margin-bottom: inherit;
}

#side-nav ul li a {
font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 1em;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.1em;
padding-top: 1em; 
}

/* Side Nav Ends Here */
/* Content Starts Here */

#content {
display: block;
padding-left: 3em;
margin-left: 12em;
}

content h2, h3, h4, h5 {
font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
font-size: 25px;
}

#content p {
font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo', serif;
padding-left: 2em;
}
/* Content Ends Here */
/* Footer Starts Here */

#foot {
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: bolder;
text-align: center;
}

#foot img {
display: inline-block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
}

/* Footer Ends Here */
```

Comment: I'd say, use `calc(...)` for the height. By the way, `display:grid` with no other grid properties doesn't do much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove `absolute` positioning and use `float` to keep you elements side by side without the huge margin you have on your `content`, use `calc` for the `content` width so it stays dynamic and `clear:both` for the footer so it stays under your content.

here's a fiddle for that ( i added some elements to the side nav to make it bigger ):  https://jsfiddle.net/6worpkj2/6/

if you want to have a fixed height on the side nav, use a number of pixels ( or em) instead of `100%` and add `overflow:scroll` to have scroll bar when you have more elements that you can fit into it, feel free to expriment :)

i hope this helps or at least gives you an idea on how to acheive what you want.

```css
/* Side Nav Starts Here */

#side-nav {
display: grid;
background-color: #0f0f0f;
width: 12em;
border: 6px solid #0f0f0f;
height: 100%;
/* position: absolute; */ /* removed */
float: left; /* added */
}

#side-nav nav {
content: "";
display: block;
border: 5px solid #ffffff;
}

#side-nav ul {
text-decoration: none;
padding-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

#side-nav ul li {
display: block;
width: 9em; /* Ask how to get the precised measure */
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
height: inherit;
margin-bottom: inherit;
}

#side-nav ul li a {
font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
display: block;
color: white;
text-align: left;
padding-bottom: 1em;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 1.1em;
padding-top: 1em; 
}

/* Side Nav Ends Here */
/* Content Starts Here */

#content {
display: block;
padding-left: 3em;
/*margin-left: 12em;*/ /* removed */
float: right; /* added */
width: calc(100% - 16em); /* added */
height: 100%; /* added */
}

content h2, h3, h4, h5 {
font-family: 'Courgette', cursive;
font-size: 25px;
}

#content p {
font-family: 'Nanum Myeongjo', serif;
padding-left: 2em;
}
/* Content Ends Here */
/* Footer Starts Here */

#foot {
font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive;
font-style: oblique;
font-weight: bolder;
text-align: center;
clear: both; /* added */
}

#foot img {
display: inline-block;
width: 32px;
height: 32px;
}

/* Footer Ends Here */
```

```html
<!-- Side Nav Starts Here -->

<span id="side-nav">
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Starting Japanese</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Particles</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Vocabulary</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Syntax</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Grammar</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kanji</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kanji</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kanji</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kanji</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kanji</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</span>    

<!-- Side Nav Ends Here -->
<!-- Content Starts Here -->

<span id="content">
<article>
    <h3>Using This</h3>
    <p>I guess you say something about this page's objective? Eh,
    <br>I'll come back to it later, I suppose.
    <br>A test
    <br>Another Text. okay.
    <br><br>asd<br>asd<br><br>asd<br><br><br><br>asdasd<br>asd<br>
    <br>asd<br>asd<br><br>asd<br><br><br><br>asdasd<br>asd<br></p>
</article>
</span>

<!-- Content Ends Here -->
<!-- Footer Starts Here -->

<footer id="foot">
<hr>
<p>Follow me on:</p>
<a href="https://www.instagram.com/justchavz/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/instagram-logo.jpg" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/JustChavz" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/twitter_logo.jpg" alt="Twitter Logo"></a>
<a href="http://chavezphotography.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logos/tumblr_logo.jpg"></a>
<hr>
</footer> 

<!-- Footer Ends Here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#side-nav {
    display: grid;
    background-color: #0f0f0f;
    width: 12em;
    border: 6px solid #0f0f0f;
    position: absolute;
    }
```

you can avoid 
<--height=100%-->

it actually makes the side-nav long to fill the entire page.
There is no problem using <--position:fixed-->in the footer,
you can also use
<--z-index:1-->
using background color for footer will also be good,if so you can set height
and can specify where it should be fixed in the screen.